# How to fit multiple models on multiple dataset in purrr?

Tags: r, purrr

I have the following tibble

```
    tribble(
  ~func, ~models, ~data,
  'lm'  ,  formula = mpg ~ disp, mtcars,
  'lm'  ,  formula = mpg ~ disp, filter(mtcars, carb < 4)
)
```

Now I would like to fit rowise the model type specified in `func` with formula `models` on a dataset `data`. I was tryin to use `invoke` like this but it doesn't work:

```
   tribble(
  ~func, ~models, ~data,
  'lm'  ,  formula = mpg ~ disp, mtcars,
  'lm'  ,  formula = mpg ~ disp, filter(mtcars, carb < 4)
)%>% invoke_map(func, list(models, data))
```

Answer (score 4):

`invoke_map` can work on a dataset like this if the list of parameters for each model is in a single variable.

That would look something like the following. Note the use of curly braces so I can call each column from the dataset within the pipe chain.

```
tribble(~func, ~params,
        'lm'  ,  list(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars),
        'lm'  ,  list(formula = mpg ~ disp, data = filter(mtcars, carb < 4) ) ) %>% 
     {invoke_map(.$func, .$params)}
```

If you need to go from your current tribble with arguments in multiple columns to arguments as a list in a single column, you could do something like

```
tribble(~func, ~models, ~data,
        'lm'  ,  formula = mpg ~ disp, mtcars,
        'lm'  ,  formula = mpg ~ disp, filter(mtcars, carb < 4) ) %>%
     mutate(params = pmap(list(models, data), list) ) %>% 
     {invoke_map(.$func, .$params)}
```

If your ultimate goal was to add the models fits to the dataset you could use `invoke_map` within `mutate`.

```
tribble(~func, ~models, ~data,
        'lm'  ,  formula = mpg ~ disp, mtcars,
        'lm'  ,  formula = mpg ~ disp, filter(mtcars, carb < 4) ) %>%
     mutate(params = pmap(list(models, data), list),
            fit = invoke_map(func, params ) )
```

Comment: Very interesting solution dear @aosmith. I was wondering whether the `params` argument to `invoke_map` always has to be a list of lists? Since I noticed you applied `list` function on both `models` and `data`. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @AnoushiravanR I didn't write out the argument names so things are a little confusing here, but I passed the `params` to the `.x` argument. Per the documentation for `.x`: "...for invoke_map a list of argument-lists the same length as .f (or length 1)."  While I don't actively remember writing this answer :-D, it looks like I was making a list of argument lists to pass to `.x`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation, I know it must have been a bit unclear a couple of years. I was looking for a similar solution and yours caught my attention. I will surely read the documentations. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 1):

We want to set up a list of lists that contains all the arguments in parallel, then call a single function that takes all of them. We'll do this with `pmap`.
Conveniently, the `modelr` package has `fit_with` that takes a modelling function, a formula, and a dataset. Since `pmap` returns a list of lists, we'll `flatten` it into a list-column in the dataframe.

```
tribble(~funcs,  ~models,       ~dat,
        glm,    "len ~ dose",   ToothGrowth,
        lm,     "len ~ dose",   filter(ToothGrowth, supp == "VC")) %>% 
  mutate(fit = flatten(pmap(.l = list(.f = funcs, .formulas = models, data = dat), 
                            .f = modelr::fit_with)))
```

> ```
> # A tibble: 2 x 4
>    funcs     models                   dat       fit
>   <list>      <chr>                <list>    <list>
> 1  <fun> len ~ dose <data.frame [60 x 3]> <S3: glm>
> 2  <fun> len ~ dose <data.frame [30 x 3]>  <S3: lm>
> ```

You can use the list-column **fit** in various model tidying functions from `broom`.

```
library(broom)

tribble(~funcs,  ~models,       ~dat,
        glm,    "len ~ dose",   ToothGrowth,
        lm,     "len ~ dose",   filter(ToothGrowth, supp == "VC")) %>% 
  mutate(fit = flatten(pmap(.l = list(.f = funcs, .formulas = models, data = dat), 
                            .f = modelr::fit_with))) %>% 
  do(map_dfr(.$fit, tidy, .id = "dataset"))
```

> ```
>   dataset        term  estimate std.error statistic      p.value
> 1       1 (Intercept)  7.422500 1.2600826  5.890487 2.064211e-07
> 2       1        dose  9.763571 0.9525329 10.250114 1.232698e-14
> 3       2 (Intercept)  3.295000 1.4270601  2.308943 2.854201e-02
> 4       2        dose 11.715714 1.0787561 10.860392 1.509369e-11
> ```

---

### Update

Another approach, more similar to your first one:

```
tribble(~funcs,  ~models,       ~dat,
        "glm",    len ~ dose,   ToothGrowth,
        "lm",     len ~ dose,   filter(ToothGrowth, supp == "VC")) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(fit = invoke_map(.f = funcs, .x = list(list(formula = models, data = dat)))) %>% 
  {map_dfr(.$fit, tidy, .id = "dataset")}
```

Note the use of quotes around the function names and the use of `rowwise` to make each list-element of the list of lists (**.x**) be length 1.